# formattable doesn't knit to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, formattable

I need some help in setting up the R Markdown environment so that the "formattable" package knits to pdf. The package Kable works, but I want to use formattable.

Problem: Rstudio's R Markdown outputs a list of numbers instead of a table, a data.frame passed in to the "formattable" package.

```
library(knitr)
library(formattable)
library(tidyr)
library(changepoint)
library(tinytex)
scores <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
  prev_score = c(10, 8, 6, 8, 8),
  cur_score = c(8, 9, 7, 8, 9),
  change = c(-2, 1, 1, 0, 1))
formattable(scores)
```

which looks like this:

[image]

It does output a table when passed to html, but it seems that it's a basic table because doesn't allow me to apply any of the format alternatives available in formattable.

Comment: try with `print(formattable(your_table_name))`

Comment: no luck, it doesn't show anything... not even the list of numbers

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation, ‘formattable’ is specifically targeting HTML, it doesn’t support PDF output. The two are fundamentally different targets an, and require specific handling, so writing code that displays HTML tables won’t automatically work in LaTeX/PDF, and vice-versa. pandoc can only handle the conversion automatically when packages create *Markdown* code for the tables, which is quite limited in what features it supports. ‘formattable’ therefore skips Markdown and directly generates HTML.

Comment: wow, if that's the reality, it'd be nice that the formattable folks consider extending the functionality to pdf, in order to be able to generate journal papers. thanks @KonradRudolph